# Select an object on the basis of its minimum attribute value from list in Java

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a class

```
public class LocationDistances {
    String locs;
    double distances;

}
```

and an ArrayList composed of LocationDistances objects in another class

```
ArrayList<LocationDistances> locsDis = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(
    new LocatoinDistances("abc",23.234556),
    new LocatoinDistances("xyz",3.3444566),
    . . . 
    . . .
    . . .

));
```

How to select LocationDistances.locs from Array list on the basis of minimum value of LocationDistances.distance from the locsDis arrayList?

Comment: You can override `equals` and `hashcode` methods of `Object` class. Or you can write a Comparator to sort your list with minimum distance on top so you can retrieve it as first element in your list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this would work if there are no duplicate distances.

```
LocationDistances min=null;
for(LocationDistances x:locsDis){
    min=(min==null||x.distances<min.distances)?x:min;
}
String minimumDistance=min.locs;
```

if there are duplicate distances use something like this

```
ArrayList<LocationDistances> min=new  ArrayList<LocationDistances>();

for(LocationDistances x:locsDis){
    if(min.size()==0||x.distances==min.get(0).distances)
           min.add(x);
    else if(x.distances<min.get(0).distances){
           min.clear();
           min.add(x);
    }               
}
```

Answer (score 7):

**If you are using Java 8 (You should :)) :**

```
locsDis.stream().min((first, second) -> Double.compare(first.distance, second.distance)).get();
```

Edit: Decided to make this post a bit more comprehensive to help those of us that are still confined to `Java < 8`  but can use the awesome library guava :)

**Java 6 & 7 With guava (Google util library):**

```
Ordering<LocationDistances> ordering = new Ordering<LocationDistances>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(LocationDistances left, LocationDistances right) {
        return Double.compare(left.distance, right.distance);
    }
};
return ordering.max(list);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a Priority Queue with a custom Comparator. (Use poll/peek for the minimum value)

```
public class MyComparator implements Comparator<LocationDistance>
{
  @Override
  public int compare(LocationDistance ld1, LocationDistance ld2)
  {
    return  Double.compare(ld1.distances, ld2.distances);
   }
}
......
......
PriorityQueue collection = new PriorityQueue<LocationDistance>(5, new MyComparator());
```

Answer (score 0):

@David Limkys is right, that would be a solution in Java 8, for java 6 & 7 the follwing would do.

```
public class MainCLass {

    /**
     * 
     */
    public MainCLass() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        LocationDistances[] arr = new LocationDistances[] {
                new LocationDistances("abc", 23.234556),
                new LocationDistances("xyz", 3.3444566), };

        ArrayList<LocationDistances> locsDis = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(arr));

        Collections.sort(locsDis, new Comparator<LocationDistances>() {
            public int compare(LocationDistances o1, LocationDistances o2) {
                return (int)( o1.distances - o2.distances);
            }
        });

    }

}

class LocationDistances {
    String locs;
    double distances;

    /**
     * @param locs
     * @param distances
     */
    public LocationDistances(String locs, double distances) {
        super();
        this.locs = locs;
        this.distances = distances;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("LocationDistances [locs=%s, distances=%s]", locs,
                distances);
    }

}
```

Comment: `return (int)( o1.distances - o2.distances);` does not work. You could end up rounding the difference to zero when the two original `double`s were not equal.

Comment: true, alternatively, we could compare them and return `0,1,-1` but i guess i was lazy :)

Answer (score 0):

You could implement Comparable on LocationDistances and sort the ArrayList using the comparator for the distance in ascending order.

```
public class LocationDistances implements Comparable {
    String locs;
    double distances;

    @Override
    public int compareTo(LocationDistances anotherLocation) {
        double otherLocDistances = ((LocationDistances)anotherLocation).getDistances();

        /* ascending order */
        return this.distances - otherLocDistance;

        /* descending order */
        //return otherLocDistance - this.distances;
    }
}
```

And then call:

```
ArrayList<LocationDistances> locsDis = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(
    new LocationDistances("abc",23.234556),
    new LocationDistances("xyz",3.3444566),
    . . . 
    . . .
    . . .

));
Collections.sort(locsDis);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what your are looking for:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;


public class Run {
    public static void main(String[]args){
        ArrayList<LocationDistances> locsDis = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(
                new LocationDistances("abc",23.234556),
                new LocationDistances("xyz",3.3444566)));

        ArrayList<Double> distances = new ArrayList<Double>();
        for (LocationDistances locationDistances : locsDis) {
            distances.add(locationDistances.getDistances());
        }
        double minimum = Collections.min(distances);
        System.out.println(minimum);
    }
}

class LocationDistances  {

    public LocationDistances(String locs, double distances) {
        this.locs = locs;
        this.distances = distances;
    }
    String locs;
    double distances;
    public String getLocs() {
        return locs;
    }
    public void setLocs(String locs) {
        this.locs = locs;
    }
    public double getDistances() {
        return distances;
    }
    public void setDistances(double distances) {
        this.distances = distances;
    }

}
```